# nginx multiple subdomains with their own config

Tags: nginx

nginx web server runs on my ubuutu server. I have multiple websites under `/var/www`. Let's keep it as simple `(myipaddres/web1 & myipaddres/web2)`

```
/var/www/web1
/var/www/web2
```

At the moment my nginx confg (single file) looks like this `(root points /var/www)`

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

But I want to have unique nginx configuration for each subdomain `(myipaddres/web1 & myipaddres/web2)` like

```
 /etc/nginx/sites-available/web1 & /etc/nginx/sites-available/web2
```

I was trying something like this, but nginx fails to reload.

```
 /etc/nginx/sites-available/web1
```

looks like this

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/web1;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
 /etc/nginx/sites-available/web2
```

looks like this

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/web2;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each server must have unique pair `server_name` and `listen $port`.

So you have two variants:

1. Change `server_name` to `localhost2` for some and add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to your /etc/hosts . (Bad variant)
2. Use `location`

`server { 
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name localhost;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location /web1 {
        root /var/www;
    }
    location /web2 {
        root /var/www;
    }
}`

or if you want has different file for each app:

`server { 
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name localhost;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    include locations/app*.conf;
}`

and two file: `/etc/nginx/locations/app1.conf` and `/etc/nginx/locations/app2.conf`
with text

`location /web1 {
        root /var/www;
    }`

and

`location /web2 {
        root /var/www;
    }`

Comment: location method works well. When just my ip address (myipaddress) is given in the browser without subdirectory location (myipaddress/web1), it loads the 404 page, is there any way to prevent this? (I don't want to load anything when just myipaddress given). thanks

Comment: `location / { 
root /var/www;
}` after locations web1 and web2